# displaying data in textboxes based on

Tags: database, vb.net, textbox

I'm not quite sure where to begin with this. This is basically how I'm trying to get it to work. I will enter the ID of a Hire Record in a textbox, hit the show hire record at which point it will materialise that hire records details in their associated textbox fields.

I attached a screenshot of the form in question. I can also create a new record as you may be able to see by typing in the details and hitting create record (this is not a problem, i already understand how to do this), but I also want to be able to display an existing records details in the textboxes again. Yes I just repeated myself but I just thought I'd try clarify my intentions further :P
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/hirerecord1.png/

Anyway, how should I go about doing this? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this slightly differently on most of my forms.  First off, when a form opens, I bind it to the data (data set, or whatever).  I display whatever record I define as the defaults (generally the last record entered.  If I want a new record, I have a button that is clicked that creates a new record in the data set and moves my form to that record.  Now you can enter your data and handle your edits, saves, etc.

As far as the pulling up a record by typing in a field I believe you could do this with one text box, but I took the easy way out and used two text boxes that are exactly the same size and location.  When your form is displaying data, handle the OnClick event for the field bound to the ID.  Hide the bound text box and display the duplicate that is unbound.  For that text box, handle the OnValidate event and set it to validate on the enter key.  The user can then type in the ID and hit enter.  You then get the ID they want from the unbound text box, clear it and hide it and cause your form to navigate to the appropriate record.

Jim

Comment: thank you for your response, I understand where you're coming from and I shall try this. thanks for your help!